# Mock a function that returns a Expression Tree in a class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, expression-trees

Scenario:

I have a class with methods, in which one method returns a expression tree.
How can I mock that method.

Code:

```
public Expression<Func<SpecFinderDataModel, bool>> BuildDynamicWhereClause(DataTableAjaxPostModel model)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<SpecFinderDataModel>(true);
        if (_stringValidator.IsValid(model.search.value))
            predicate = _basicSearchService.DoSearch(model.search.value, predicate);
        var searchData = model.columns.Where(x => x.search.value != null);
        predicate = _advancedSearchService.DoSearch(model.isActive, searchData, predicate);
        return predicate;
    }
```

Here `_advancedSearchService.DoSearch()` this method returns a `Expression<Func<SpecFinderDataModel, bool>>`. I wrote a test which is given below

Test:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("BuildDynamicWhereClause")]
public void BuildDynamicWhereClauseTest()
{
    DataTableAjaxPostModel searchmodel = new DataTableAjaxPostModel()
    {
        columns = new List<Column>()
        {
            new Column() {
                data ="Status",
                orderable ="true",
                searchable ="true",
                search = new Search() {
                    regex = "false",
                    value ="TestStatus"
                }
            }
        },
        search = new Search()
    };

    IFinderBuildQueryFlow _finderBuildQueryFlow = new FinderBuildQueryFlow(
        _mockBasicSearchService.Object, _mockAdvancedSearchService.Object, _mockStringValidator.Object);

    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<SpecFinderDataModel>(true);
    _mockStringValidator.Setup(x => x.IsValid(searchmodel.search.value)).Returns(false);
    var searchData = searchmodel.columns.Where(x => x.search.value != null);
    _mockAdvancedSearchService.Setup(x => x.DoSearch(searchmodel.isActive, searchData, predicate).Compile()(model)).Returns(true);
    var test = _finderBuildQueryFlow.BuildDynamicWhereClause(searchmodel).Compile()(model);
}
```

Everything before 
`_mockAdvancedSearchService.Setup(x => x.DoSearch(searchmodel.isActive, searchData, predicate).Compile()(model)).Returns(true);` works fine.
But I don't know how to mock `advancedSearch.DoSearch()` method.

Any advice would be really helpful. Thanks

Update #1:

This is the error when that line of code is executed

[image]

Update #2:

[image]

so here the predicate is returned as `null`.

and in the test
I'm getting the error like this
[image]

Comment: This code `_advancedSearchService.DoSearch(model.isActive, searchData, predicate)` is returning predicate of type `Expression<Func<SpecFinderDataModel, bool>>`, then why in Mock you are compiling it to Func and returning the Value true, it is due to type Mismatch its not able to work, instead try returning (s => true), which will be filled in for the return type

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mock the call to _advancedSearchService.DoSearch() you will have to set it up as follows:

```
Expression<Func<SpecFinderDataModel, bool>> query = model => true;
_mockAdvancedSearchService.Setup(x => x.DoSearch(searchmodel.isActive, It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Column>>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<SpecFinderDataModel, bool>>>())).Returns(query);
```

Given that the `searchdata` parameter is created in the method itself you will need to accept any value for it.

Given that the `predicate` parameter is created in the method itself you will need to accept any value for it.

Comment: Thanks Mel, But I need to return a bool value i.e true. If I use `Expression<Func<SpecFinderDataModel, bool>> query = true` its not working. How can I do that?

Comment: you need to return a Func that takes a model and returns a boolean, for example: query = model => true;

Comment: Hmm. Even if I return true, I'm getting a NullReference Error. at that code.

Comment: A NullReference is a different exception. Where do you get it and did you initialize all the values?

Comment: Hi Mel, Please See my Update#2 in the question. I'm getting those.

Comment: please specify how you set up mocking for the DoSearch method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177321/discussion-between-mel-gerats-and-ranjith-varadan).